# ActiveRecord - nested includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to perform the following query in Rails 5 in a way that it doesn't trigger N+1 queries when I access each events.contact:

```
events = @company.recipients_events
                 .where(contacts: { user_id: user_id })
```

I tried some combinations of .includes, .references and .eager_loading, but none of them worked. Some of them returned an SQL error, and other ones returned a nil object when I access events.contact.

Here's a brief version of my associations:

```
class Company
   has_many :recipients
   has_many :recipients_events, through: :recipients, source: :events
end

class Recipient
   belongs_to :contact
   has_many :events, as: :eventable
end

class Event
   belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true
end

class Contact
   has_many :recipients
end
```

What would be the correct way to achieve what I need?

Comment: what is your view snippet

Comment: I'm testing using rails console

Comment: Can  you try using something like this 
@company.recipients_events.includes(:contact)
                 .where(contacts: { user_id: user_id }).
and show errors if any

Comment: Here's the error: "Can't join 'Event' to association named 'contact'; perhaps you misspelled it?". I believe this happens because Event associates with Recipient, and Recipient associates with Contact.

Comment: I also tried: @company.recipients_events.includes(flow_recipient: :contact).where(contacts: { user_id: user_id }). In this case, there are no errors, but everytime I access event.contact, Rails performs two new queries for FlowRecipient load and Contact load.

Comment: DEBUG -- :   FlowRecipient Load (2.8ms)  SELECT  "flow_recipients".* FROM "flow_recipients" WHERE "flow_recipients"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]

DEBUG -- :   Contact Load (5.1ms)  SELECT  "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Answer (score 3):

If you already know user_id when you load @company, I'd do something like this:

```
@company = Company.where(whatever)
  .includes(recipients: [:recipients_events, :contact])
  .where(contacts: { user_id: user_id })
  .take
events = @company.recipients_events
```

OR, if not:

```
events = Company.where(whatever)
  .includes(recipients: [:recipients_events, :contact])
  .where(contacts: { user_id: user_id })
  .take
  .recipients_events
```

The ActiveRecord query planner will determine what it thinks is the best way to get that data. It might be 1 query per table without the `where`, but when you chain `includes().where()` you will probably get 2 queries both with left outer joins on them.

Comment: events = Company.includes(recipients: [:events, :contact]).where(id: 2, contacts: { user_id: 6 }).first.recipients_events. When I execute this, Rails performs 2 queries: one joining everything and one to select all company events. Until here, includes seems to be working. However, when I access events.first.contact, Rails perform 2 more queries: one to load the Recipient and another one to load the Contact. And it happens everytime I access a new event, for example, events.second.contact. Is that the expected behavior? I thought it would also join or preload all of the recipients and contacts.

Comment: You want to be sure to `include` the named association you're going to use. In this case, try to restructure `recipients_events` into you're `includes` statement. For example: `events = Company.where(id: 2).includes(recipients: [:recipients_events, :contact]).where(contacts: { user_id: 6 }).take.recipients_events` OR `events = Company.where(id: 2).includes(recipients: [:events, :contact]).where(contacts: { user_id: 6 }).take.recipients.map(&:events)`

Comment: That's illegible as a comment, I added it to the answer.